# Creating chunks of dataframe columns from a set of dataframe column in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a dataframe with 100 columns -

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7| ...     Column100
```

I want to make chunk of 10 dataframe column -
For example -

- chunk1 will have - Column1 to Column10
- chunk2 will have - Column11 to Column20
- chunk3 will have - Column21 to Column30

  ...
- chunk10 will have column 91 to column 100

Kindly provide an optimize solution for this problem statement.

I tried with `df.schema.fields.foreach` but not working. looking for better approach

Comment: Yes, databricks only.

Answer (score 0):

For get 10 dataframes from one, with 10 columns in each, method `grouped` can be used for split all columns on groups:

```
val columnCount = 100

val values = 1 to columnCount
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row.fromSeq(values)))
val columns = (1 to columnCount).map(idx => StructField(name = "Column" + idx, dataType = IntegerType, nullable = true))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(columns))

val chunkSize = 10
val chunks = df.columns.grouped(chunkSize).toSeq
val result: Seq[DataFrame] = chunks.map(columns => df.select(columns.head, columns.tail: _*))
result.head.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8|Column9|Column10|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
|1      |2      |3      |4      |5      |6      |7      |8      |9      |10      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+
```